# Making buttons available on clause

Tags: android

there is a part in my app where I want buttons to be available only if you have enough coins and by clicking the button your coins decrease so buttons should be disabled again if the score becomes less than 2 
this is my button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/shoes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tie"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:onClick="shoes"
    android:text="how to tie your shoes !!"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="25sp" />
```

and this is the java

```
public void shoes (View view) {
    coins = coins -2 ;
    SharedPreferences mycoins = getSharedPreferences("mycoins", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mycoins.edit();
    editor.putInt("coins",coins) ;
    editor.commit();

    textCoins.setText(""+coins);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shQ5U8my8jA")));
}
```

Comment: what is not working in your code?

Comment: inside your shoes method: `if(coins<2){view.setEnabled(false);}` at the end

Comment: Your View in that method is in this case your button

Answer (score 0):

The view that is passed to the method is the button, so you need to set that view to disabled.

```
public void shoes (View view) {
    coins = coins - 2 ;

    if( coins < 2){
         view.setEnabled(false);
    }

    SharedPreferences mycoins = getSharedPreferences("mycoins", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mycoins.edit();
    editor.putInt("coins",coins) ;
    editor.commit();

    textCoins.setText(""+coins);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shQ5U8my8jA")));
}
```

Comment: this button is the onClick button so the if condition will not work if I have not clicked it and also it won't  enable the button again